# Do we say "you need to strap or fasten the canopy after folding the umbrella so that it won't unfold"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [strap somebody/something + adv./prep](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/strap_2). to fasten somebody/something in
>   place using a strap or straps
>
> He strapped the knife to his leg.
>
> Everything had to be strapped down to stop it from sliding around.
>
> Are you strapped in (= wearing a seat belt in a car, plane, etc.)?

---

> [fasten](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fasten?q=fasten) [transitive, intransitive] to close or join together the two parts of
>   something; to become closed or joined together SYNONYM do up
>
> fasten something Fasten your seat belts, please.
>
> Emma shivered and fastened the top button of her coat.
>
> fasten something up He fastened up his coat and hurried out.
>
> fasten (something) with something The garment is fastened with a
>   sash.
>
> fasten + adv./prep. The dress fastens at the back.
>
> a short yellow skirt which fastens up the side.
>
> The gown fastens down the front with Velcro.

---

After you fold your umbrella, you see a strap on the canopy as shown in this picture

[image]

Then, we have to "**strap or fasten the canopy so that the umbrella won't unfold**" as shown in the below picture

[image]

What is the generic way to express it?

can we say "**you need to strap or fasten the canopy after folding the umbrella so that it won't unfold**"?

Comment: I have never heard “canopy” used in connection with an umbrella but I suppose it does adequately describe the fabric element. Your choice of words is perfectly understandable but perhaps not entirely idiomatic. In instructions I’d expect something like “Use the velcro fastener to keep the umbrella neatly closed while not in use.”

Comment: Or just "Fasten the strap of the umbrella after you fold it".